# Where is the width of a slick.js slide calculated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I have tried using the slick initial setting 'variableWidth: true', but then the carousel container (.slick-track) is set to 20000px wide and does not respond to screen width, so then the width of each slide is not responsive either. **So, to be clear, 'variableWidth: true' is not useful to me.**

I have seen the questions here:

[How can I change the width and height of slides on Slick Carousel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23273506/how-can-i-change-the-width-and-height-of-slides-on-slick-carousel)

and here:

[fixed width slides with slick carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25775152/fixed-width-slides-with-slick-carousel)

but I do not want to set the width of each slide as a fixed pixel amount; They need to be responsive.

I'd really like to know where the width of a slide is calculated, when 'variableWidth' is left at the default of 'false'; The carousel is **very** close to looking correct (each slide just needs to be slightly wider). I've been looking through the slick.js plugin but cannot find a reference to 'width' that is applied as css.

There are several references to 'px' in the plugin, but these are to do with either padding or position.

Does anyone know where, or how, in the 'slick.js' code, the width of a  carousel slide is calculated, **when 'variableWidth' is set to false?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help anybody else, if it's too late for you.
I just dived into the code, as I was looking for this too.

The width of every slide is set in at the last line of the `setDimensions()` function. (Slick 1.8.1)

```
if (_.options.variableWidth === false)
    _.$slideTrack.children('.slick-slide').width(_.slideWidth - offset);
```